# How do I get my two laptops to communicate with each other through IPv6?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ipv6

I am new to IPv6 communication and network settings, so I am not sure how to setup these IPv6 addresses.

I have two separate laptops running Windows 7 and Windows 10 that I am connecting with an Ethernet cable. I want both of them to have a specific user-defined IPv6 address.

How do I get them to communicate with one another? I just want to configure the IPv6 addresses (somehow) and then ping each other through cmd prompt.

Comment: "How do I get them to communicate with one another?" - Connect them to the same IPv6 subnet via a switch/router is the simplest method.

Comment: Is there any device like router between those machines? If not, then just use static IPs using this block `fd00::/8`. See more [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv6_addresses).

Comment: There is no router between my machines. I'm connecting them both with an Ethernet cable to the Ethernet ports on the back of my laptops. I read the article that you sent Biswa. How would I configure my computer's static IPv6 addresses to fd00::/8 and would both computer's be configured to the same IPv6 address? I go into control panel -> network and sharing center -> Ethernet Status-> Ethernet Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), but it won't let me enter /8 into the IPv6 address field.

Comment: @Imozeb fd00::/8 just means "all IPv6 addresses that start with 0xFD as their first 8 bits". So make your first machine fd00::1, and your second machine fd00::2.

Please also note that IPv6 is very good at automatically setting up link-local IPv6 addresses for every active interface, so both of your machines already have self-assigned fe80:: link-local addresses that you could already use to ping each other, without manually setting up any addresses. But when using fe80:: link-local addresses, you may have to specify the scope ID at the end after a `%`.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks. I managed to change my first machine's IPv6 address to fd00:1 with a subnet prefix of 64. Ipconfig displays the correct IPv6 address. My second machine has a problem. After I finish changing the IPv6 address on my second machine, and use ipconfig on it to check the address, it resets back to 'Obtain IPv6 address automatically.' In addition ipconfig is only displaying my second machine's IPv4 address and not my machine's IPv6 address. Why does it keep resetting?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to *configure* addresses to communicate in IPv6 world, like in IPv4. If your computers both belong to a single broadcast domain (in other words, connect to a single switch), they already have predefined link-local addresses you can use to communicate.

If you still feel uncomfortable without *configuring* something, you can set up unique local addresses. As mentioned before, this addresses must begin with fd00, but there are several additional restrictions. First of all, [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) requires you to generate 40 unique bits, combine them with fd00, thus obtaining /48 prefix. Then you have to subnet this /48 prefix to /64, take one of them, and use two arbitrary addresses from it for the hosts.